# PHP compare 2 folders to find missing files

Tags: php, compare

I have two image folders original/ and thumbs/ but the file count differs (thumbs/ has less) so I need to find which images are missing, file names are exactly the same IE no prefix on thumbs, so as the title says how can I compare both folders and output a list of the missing images?

**Update:**

None of the answers seemed to do what I wanted but I came up with this very crude answer

NOT ADVISABLE TO USE!!

We give body a dark background and then style img with a bright standout color:

```
<style>
    body{background:#000;}
    img {height:10px;width:10px;background:pink;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;margin:5px;}
</style>
```

The PHP:

```
// Read dir ...
        $images = glob('original/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);

// throw out a foreach ...
        foreach($images as $image) 
         {

// using str_replace switch folders 
          $image  = str_replace('original/', 'thumbs/', $image);

// echo result 
          $result = '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="m" />';
          echo $result;
}
```

After a long wait and near killing your system all images show, up now you simply look at each and find the missing ones.

See result here:
http://s12.postimage.org/5kcsvs48r/missing.jpg

Like I said this is a very crude way of doing it and very server intensive, possibly okay if only a few images but then your likely to find them easily by reading but I had over 8000 images to go through, anyway like I said before this is not advisable but I thought I would share my answer anyway good or bad.

Comment: have you tried opendir(); for a list of files in a directory?

Comment: Or atleast, what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 7):

A way to start:

```
$original = array_map('basename', glob('original/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE));
$thumbs = array_map('basename', glob('thumbs/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE));
$missing_thumbs = array_diff($original, $thumbs);
$missing_original = array_diff($thumbs, $original);
```

**Edit note:** I've missed that `array_diff()` won't work here since `glob()` array's includes pathnames... Patched with `basename()` mapping, now it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

php.net has a lot of documentation and discussion on how to got through directories (see: [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and so on).

### Example 1

This example reads a flat directory (no sub-directories) and compares them, leaving the result in the array at the end.

```
$original = glob('path/to/original/*.*');
$thumbs   = glob('path/to/thumbs/*.*');

$missing = array('original' => array(), 'thumbs' => array());

$missing['original']   = array_diff($thumbs, $original);
$missing['thumbs'] = array_diff($original, $thumbs);

print_r($missing); // Prints out a sorted array of the missing files for each dir
```

The problem with this example is if you have sub-folders in either folder. To handle that, you have to use a recursive structure like below.

### Example 2

This example utilizes recursion to find *all* of the missing files through *all* of the sub-directories of `thumbs/` and `original/`.

```
/* Returns an associative array of all files under a directory,
including those inside of sub-directories, using recursion */
function scan($path) {
  $dir = opendir($path);
  
  while(false !== ($f = readdir($handle)))
    if(is_dir($f))
        $files[$f] = scan($path.$f.'/');
      else
        $files[$f] = $f;
    
    return $files;
  }

$original = scan('path/to/original/');
$thumbs = scan('path/to/thumbs/');

$missing['thumbs'] = array_diff($original, $thumbs);
$missing['original'] = array_diff($thumbs, $original);

print_r($missing);
print_r($original);
print_r($thumbs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from [www.php.net/opendir/](http://www.php.net/opendir/):

```
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

You can do this for both of your directories and place the file names in separate arrays instead of echoing them.  Then compare the arrays to find the missing files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalsDir = 'path';
$originalsArray = array();
if ($handle = opendir($originalsDir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $originalsArray[] = $entry;
    }
    closedir($handle);
} else {
    die('Could not open originals dir: ' . $originalsDir);
}
$thumbsDir = 'path';
$thumbsArray = array();
if ($handle = opendir($thumbsDir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $thumbsArray[] = $entry;
    }
    closedir($handle);
} else {
    die('Could not open thumbs dir: ' . $thumbsDir);
}

$missingThumbs = array_diff($originalsArray, $thumbsArray);
```

See [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff), [opendir()](http://php.net/opendir), [readdir()](http://php.net/readdir)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir_files1 = array();
$dir_files2 = array();

//Do this twice, Once for each directory
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files1')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $dir_files1[] = $entry;
    }
}

//Then compare the two arrays with eachother
foreach($dir_files1 as $d1)
{
 $match =false;
 foreach($dir_files2 as $d2)
 {
    if($d1==$d2)
     $match=true;
 }
 if(!$match)
   do_something();
}
```